# toDataURL() can't save contents of HTML5 canvas with JS Interop in Blazor Webassembly?

Tags: javascript, c#, html5-canvas, blazor

I'm trying to build a rudimentary paint app using Blazor Wasm as a learning exercise. Drawing to the canvas through the API provided by Blazor.Extensions.Canvas seems to work fine, but I'm trying to save the contents of the canvas to a PNG and I'm running into issues. Since there is no method for this in the C# wrapper that Blazor.Extensions.Canvas provides, I have a simple JS function inside a script tag in index.html:

```
function saveCanvasContents(canvcont) //this parameter is supposed to be the canvas context object
{
    return canvcont.toDataURL();
}
```

Which is being called from the C# component like this:

```
Object testObject = await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<Object>("saveCanvasContents", new object[] {_context});
```

`_context` here is the Blazor Extensions Canvas' context, which is generated in `OnAfterRenderAsync` by `_context = await CanvasReference.CreateCanvas2DAsync();`.

Anyway, running this produces `Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: canvcont.toDataURL is not a function` in the browser console. My intuition here would be that this is because whatever I'm passing it isn't a HTMLCanvasElement and as such doesn't have a toDataURL. Passing it the reference to the canvas component (CanvasReference above, it's of type BECanvasComponent) has the same result. Am I misunderstanding something fundamental about Blazor's JS interop / JS in general, or is there a better way of going about this in Blazor?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I had to pass the method my `_context.Canvas`. Everything else I passed it was referring to a BECanvas component, which wraps an HTML5 canvas, rather than a regular old HTML canvas, so it would make sense that one of those doesn't have a toDataURL method. Good luck to anyone finding this in the future.